# Croatian letters in Java Program

Tags: java, fonts, playframework, itext

I need help your help on croatian letters in my program. On the website (play framework) you can put in names. The name will be saved and a PDF file will be created (with iText) where the string the user typed in is shown. I want to use the font lucida bright. The problem is that there are non-german letters in the names that are not shown. I also tried to convert it into unicode (/u----) but it also doesn't work. I tried to use utf-8 like this in the iText doc:

```
String name = new String(e.getName().getBytes("UTF-8"));
// e is the object where the name and some other infos are saved
```

and in the html where the user can type in the name

```
<meta name="language" content="cr">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but it doesn't work completely.

In lucida bright (font) are only Š and š correctly shown and in times new roman Š, Ž, š and ž. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a font in iText's PDF generation then you have to add it

As in

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman");
document.add(new Paragraph("Times-Roman", font));
```

For more information see [iText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=212)

Comment: i've done it with    
`BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("conf/fonts/Lucida_Bright.ttf",BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`  
and 
`canvas.setFontAndSize(bf, 7f);`

Comment: thats because i'm using `canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "ČĆĐŠŽčćđšž", x, y, 0);`

Comment: the problem is, that's my first time with itext :). i must put the text on a specific x/y coordinate. i solved it with the x and y var in show text aligned. how can i transform the text with your method?

Comment: it could be helpful if you tell me how to transform the text with the add method :)

Comment: ok i solved the problem. it was the font lucida bright. the times_roman font of the basefont class is also not working. i copied a font of the C:/system/fonts folder and it works. now i have a problem with the ttc files but i thing i can solve it with google :) thanks for your help